# align 3 items on a row with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Working on a react native project which there's an array of days of the week, currently trying to display 3 days per row and then break to the next line but I'm having difficulty.

```js
<View style={{ width: '100%', alignItems: 'center' }}>
  {tags.map(item => (
    <Text
      style={{
        width: '30%',
        backgroundColor: ' green',
        color: 'white',
        borderRadius: 20,
        paddingRight: 5,
      }}>
      {item.label}
    </Text>
  ))}
</View>;
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
Monday Tuesday Wednesday
Thursday Friday
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `FlatList` with `numColumns={3}`.

**Please check following code**

```
 <FlatList  numColumns={3}
                    data={[  
                        {key: 'Android'},{key: 'iOS'}, {key: 'Java'},{key: 'Swift'},  
                        {key: 'Php'},{key: 'Hadoop'},{key: 'Sap'},  
                        {key: 'Python'},{key: 'Ajax'}, {key: 'C++'},  
                        {key: 'Ruby'},{key: 'Rails'},{key: '.Net'},  
                        {key: 'Perl'},{key: 'Sap'},{key: 'Python'},  
                        {key: 'Ajax'}, {key: 'C++'},{key: 'Ruby'},  
                        {key: 'Rails'},{key: '.Net'},{key: 'Perl'}  
                    ]}  
                    renderItem={({item}) =>  
                        <Text style={{  
        padding: 10,  
        fontSize: 18,  
        height: 44
                        }}  
                              >{item.key}</Text>}  

                />
```

Please check this demo

https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/flat-list

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use a `<Flatlist />` component, it has a prop called [`numColums`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#numcolumns) that basically render items when `horizontal={false}` and will zig-zag like a `flexWrap` layout.

So you can do something like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';

const data = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];

export default () => (
  <FlatList
    data={data}
    numColumns={3}
    style={styles.container}
    renderItem={({ item: day }) => <Text style={styles.element}>{day}</Text>}
  />
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  element: {
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    margin: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

You will have something like this:

[image]

Check out the snack at https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/3-col-flatlist

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to force wrap, you can add the `flexGrow` property to your items and set `flexWrap: 'wrap'` on your container view:

```
<View style={{ width: '100%', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
 {
tags.map((item) => (
   <Text style={{width: '30%', backgroundColor:'green', color:'white', borderRadius:20, paddingRight: 5, flexGrow:1}}>{item.label}</Text>
))
}
 </View>
```

It will get a bit more difficult if you need to do something like CSS `nth-child` functionality. Since styles are plain objects in RN, you can achieve that by assigning a function to your `width` or `flexGrow` properties like so:

```
<Text style={[{width: '30%', backgroundColor:'green', color:'white', borderRadius:20, paddingRight: 5}, { flexGrow: this.isNthChild(item) ? 0 : 1}]}></Text>
```

Then implement `isNthChild` on your component:

```
function isNthChild(item) { return item.key >= 3; // you can go wild and implement your logic here, this is just an example }
```